# Emulator android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using ***Android studio 3.5.2***

I am getting following error:

`Emulator: process finished with exit code` any one can help me I posted a question type like this but someone said we need more issue about your problem such as screenshot Error's and so on. So this is the

**Error message:** `Emulator:process finished with exit code -1073740286 (0×C0000602)`

Comment: What is your problem? When you launch the emulator, it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes when ever i launch the emulator it doesn't work and i am getting this error -> Emulator: process finished with exit code -1073740286 (0xC0000602).   My machine is  HP spectre×360 13inch

Comment: Hello i am still looking answer, please help me i posted my question before 1 week